# Access VBA: Memory control, mdb file size

Tags: ms-access, memory-management, memory-leaks, vba, filesize

What are some good practices to control the memory you block up with VBA.
For example, I declare objects, open connections, open recordsets, etc, but does that memory get freed again?

When I started the project I'm working on, my Access .mdb file was only 300kb, now its 13Mb!!!! (and its only 300 lines of code)
Everytime I run my code, I can see my .mdb file size grow by a few hundred kb.

So please help me out on how I should go about on maintaining my file size.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always compact and repair your Access database.  In Access 2003 this option is available under Tools > Database Utilities > Compact and Repair.

The database always increases in size when you are working with it.

One thing you can always do with VBA is make sure that you Close your connections and recordsets once you are finished using them.

Comment: wow thats a cool feature, is there anyway that I can automatically call that feature from within? (haha I doubt it but it'd be cool!)

Comment: My database is open all the time. So I have a timer form that stays open and compacts it at night.  However 13MB is still really small for Access. My database gets to over 1GB, so size gets to be more of a concern at that point.

Answer (score 1):

In Access 2010 you can use the "Compact and Repair Database" tool (on the "Database Tools" tab) to clean up your database. This will shrink the file size as much as possible.